# Is anybody having issues with comments in html after upgrading to snow leopard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just upgraded to Snow Leopard and now I'm having this weird issue.  Has anybody seen this issue?  Ruby comments in the html are causing weird issues.
for exmaple:

```
<!-- /app/views/convs/_conv_detail_wiki.rhtml -->
<% # Prereq: conv,
#         seed %>
<% # NOTE: you can implicit pass @keywords to this partial for highlighting purposes %>

<div id="<%= conv.dom_id(seed) %>" class="<%= conv.to_css %>">
```

I have this code at the top of one of my partials.

This gets rendered:

```
 <!-- /app/views/convs/_conv_detail_wiki.rhtml -->
wiki-2236-7937" class="k-conv-root  k-wiki-item"&gt;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps put this onto one line?

```
<% # Prereq: conv,
#         seed %>
```

into this;

```
<% # Prereq: conv, seed %>
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't do anything.  Removing the comment all together, fixes it.  But that doesn't explain why its broke in the first place.